# how to use Valet server with a port different from 80?

Tags: laravel-valet

Do you know of any way to run Valet on a port other than 80? I need it because it's going to conflict with MAMP (and don't want to change MAMP ports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answer here... Anyway I'm answering by myself... One way is just proxying:

```
valet proxy [mydirectory] http://127.0.0.1:[any port]
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet#proxying-services

Comment: `valet proxy --secure custom-host-name http://127.0.0.1:[any port]` ;)

Comment: can I use it for my nodejs project that is running on port 3000 ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably late, but just for anyone still facing this issue even after running the command above. Just  run valet port. It will list all port been used on nginx both http and s. To change https port run `valet port [your port] --https`. And for http just run `valet port [your port]`.

**NOTE** Replace [your port] with 9090 or 8080,or any port you desire

Comment: The result is `Command "port" is not defined.`